# Text in tcolorbox by using new enviroment

Tags: tcolorbox

how can I insert a text line under the picture? If I try to take a text after \includegraphics[...] it goes wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins, raster} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,
blend before title=dash hang,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum{}
\begin{myfigure}[nofloat]{A tcolorbox figure with quite a long title}
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    \\ example-text
\end{myfigure}
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You use `capture=hbox`. That won't work with line breaks.

Comment: What have I use instead?

Comment: What is your aim? Do you want hboxed content? Then you'll have a problem, because line breaks won't work. Do you want vboxed content? Then you can just remove that capture option. But currently, it is not clear what you want. Another thing: You want every float to be centered, what should happen with the image?

Comment: What I in fact want is a colorbox with the picture in there and a small text for source information under the picture. The caption should be in the title-frame on the top

Comment: Shall it be centered? And shall the box be hboxed (only as wide as the content)?

Comment: Yes, all content should be centered and be hboxed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @TeXnician and from the *tcolorbox* package:

> /tcb/capture=hbox:
>   ... The content cannot have a lower part and cannot be broken...

But we can get arround this by adding `tikznode` option to `myfigure` definition

```
\documentclass{article}

% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins, raster} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{
  tikznode, % add this option
  float=htb,
  capture=hbox,
  blend before title=dash hang,
  title={#2},
  every float=\centering,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum{}
\begin{myfigure}[nofloat]{A tcolorbox figure with quite a long title}
  \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image} \\
  example-text
\end{myfigure}
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because of a another reason I had to remove the _float=htb_. In fact it is still not working, after adding _tikznode_. My text is in the same line, where the picture i shown.

Comment: Even if  `float=htb` is removed it should be ok! Try the to copy past the code I have posted.